# Prove conditions given pairwise independence

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, independence

Show that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise independent events and $P(B \cap C)$ is not $0$, then the following conditions are equivalent:

(1) $P(A)=P(A \mid  B \cap C)$

(2) $P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

Comment: should this question be tagged with the `self-study` tag? read this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (1) $\implies$ (2): write out the definition of conditional probability for the right hand side of (1).

Hint for (2) $\implies$ (1): try dividing the right hand side of (2) by some stuff to make it look equation (1).

Comment: I appreciate the hints, but I am genuinely confused. Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: @user196418 what are you confused about, specifically?

Comment: I do not know how to use the conditional probability equation to get back to P(A). I know what it is and how to write it, but I don't know if anything cancels out or why it would to get me back to P(A). For part 1. Part 2, I don't understand what I would be dividing the right side of the equation by to get it to look like (1). I don't understand dividing anything from it at all.

Comment: @user196418 maybe I don't understand what you mean exactly, but in going from (1) to (2), you don't need to prove (1). Rather, you assume it is true, and show that its true-ness implies that (2) is true. That means you take (1), re-arrange it, and then voila, it's (2).

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. So, I have the equation for the conditional probability equal to part 1, and now how do I get it to equal part 2? Since part 2 doesn't involve conditional probability, it is independent events, how do I make that connection?

Comment: @user196418 right there’s no conditional probability in (2). Once you plug in the definition of conditional probability in (1), then it’s gone, right. And you won’t quite have (2) completely after plugging in that definition of conditional probability, but maybe one of the other assumptions can help to make it look exactly like (2).